# mysql select specified key_name and key_value from json encode field

Tags: php, mysql, regex, json

I want to display specified key_name and key_value of a field with mysql where record is encoded json format

```
id_user           dtl_master              date    
  1         {"el1":"2","el2":"3"}       2015/01/01
  2         {"el1":"2","el2":"3"}       2015/01/01 
  3         {"el1":"5","el2":"6"}       2015/01/01
```

My query to filter select is

```
SELECT id_user,dtl_master FROM tb_inputdata WHERE dtl_master REGEXP '"el2":"([^"]*)4([^"]*)"';
```

but it return :

```
 id_user           dtl_master            
      1         {"el1":"6","el2":"4"}
```

I wanted to display like this

```
 id_user              el2            
   1                   4
```

I know REGEXP not running on SELECT, but only on WHERE, anybody know how to SELECT only related key_name or key_value?

Thank You

Comment: well a have a ton of data, I should save each pair variable and value on same field, so json format is the solution right now

Comment: If your application manually encodes stuff and just throws it in the database, then your application logic itself also has to take care with unfolding it again.

Comment: Bad design, however just `json_decode` and use `el2` when fetching the rows from the result.

Comment: Hi, I don't want display and parse it in application (php) for somereason (memory and efficiency), I tried to do this on mysql first

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend going to NoSQL but one way you can extract it is by doing:

```
SELECT id_user, common_schema.extract_json_value(dtl_master,'/el2') AS el2 WHERE dtl_master REGEXP '"el2":"([^"]*)4([^"]*)"';
```

If you plan to get `common_schema`. Installation documentation [here](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/install.html).

But of course you can always select using regex, by `SELECT`ing a `PREG_REPLACE()` value. This isn't default in MySQL alone either; you'd need to get something like [this](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg#readme).

Comment: Is `common_schema` default to MySQL, or is that something you have to add?

Comment: @mopo922 It's something you have to add. If he's going to work with JSON's, he might as well.

Comment: thank you for answering,but it require additional stuff to be installed https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/ also 
extract_json_value() is CPU intensive according to documentation. I still waiting for another answer

Comment: Can you add instructions to get `common_schema` to your answer?

Comment: @ReidsMekeMeke Best answer you'll receive is switch to NoSQL. Although I'm waiting as well.

Comment: Thanks shahar, I still confused how to best way store multiple value on 1 field and select filter it by specified value or key on it also display specified value or key it self, It may out of normalization logic, but all I need is reduce row of data instead multiple row data for 1 input